# Finding second vector given a vector and the angle between the two

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am given a vector **w** = (1,1) I need to find a second vector **v** so that the angle between **w** and **v**, $\theta$ = $\pi/3$. I am supposed to use this formula to find the solution ||**v||** ||**w**|| cos($\theta$) = **w** • **v**

I am at a point where I even think that this is impossible unless I make an assumption but that is not allowed

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The solution isn’t unique, so if you only want to produce one such vector then yes, you will have to make some additional assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to find $v=(a,b)$ such that

$$\frac{v\cdot w}{|v||w|}=\cos \theta=\frac12 \implies 2(a+b)=\sqrt 2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

$$a^2+4ab+b^2=0 \implies b^2\left(x^2+4x+1\right)=0 \quad x=\frac a b$$

$$\implies x_1=-2+\sqrt 3\quad x_2=-2-\sqrt 3$$

therefore we obtain

- $v_1=(-2+\sqrt 3,1)$
- $v_2=(2+\sqrt 3,-1)$

To check we can see geometrically that since vector $w$ is at $45°$ couterclockwise from $x$ axis the vectors $v_i$ are rotated of $-15°$ and $105°$ with respect to $x$ axis.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose another vector $v= (a,b)$.
Then according to the formula, you need 
\begin{equation}
 w.v= \Vert w \Vert \Vert v \Vert \cos \frac{\pi}{2} = 0
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 (a,b).(1,1) = 0
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 a + b = 0
\end{equation}
i.e. $b = -a$
Hence any vector $v = (a,-a)$ will do. Examples are $v = (1,-1)$, $v =(2,-2)$, $v = (\pi, -\pi)$ .. etc.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the response I have one question thought. How did you know that v . w  = ||w|| ||v|| cos π/2 would be equal to zero?

Comment: No problem .. it is because you mentioned that $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ so $\cos \theta = 0$

Comment: I just noticed that I made a typo.. The angle between the vectors is actually pi over 3

Comment: In case the angle is $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$, then you'd get 
\begin{equation}
 w.v = \Vert w \Vert \Vert v \Vert \cos \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{1}{2}\Vert w \Vert \Vert v \Vert 
\end{equation}
But $w =(1,1)$ so $\Vert w \Vert = \sqrt{2}$, hence we get
\begin{equation}
 a+b = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}
\end{equation}
So you should find $(a,b)$ that solve this.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, the only problem is that I have no idea how to solve an equation with two unknowns. I got to the point where I have $4a^2 + 8ab + 4b^2 = 0$ and this is not something that I can solve...

Comment: \begin{equation}  a+b = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \end{equation} does not give $4a^2 + 8ab + 4b^2 = 0$ .. Try again :) @nicks6853

Comment: I'm sorry, it gives $2a^2 + 8ab + 2b^2 = 0$ but I still have no way of solving that

Comment: All you have to do is find a pair of values $(a,b)$ that satisfy the above. Can you ?

Comment: No I cannot, that is what I can't get past.

Comment: Just solve one as a function of the other, i.e.
\begin{equation}
 a^2 + 4ab + b^2 = 0 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Let's say $b$ is given (ex. set $b = 1$)  and $a$ is the unknown so equation $(1)$ is quadratic in $a$, so find $a$ in terms of $b$. You find the discriminant in terms of $b$, then the roots ..

Comment: For example if $b = 1$, you will have to find $a$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
 a^2 + 4a + 1 = 0
\end{equation}
So the discriminant is $$\Delta = 4^2 - 4(1)(1) = 12$$
So you have two $a$'s
\begin{equation}
 a = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{12}}{2}
\end{equation}
which are approximately $a_1 = -2 + \sqrt{3}$ and $a_2 =-2 - \sqrt{3}$. Now, check the above equation for any of those $a$'s combined with $b = 1$, does it give zero ? (well it should)